# Used IDs are not available anymore in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, caching, memory, browser

I am using Python and Selenium to **scrape** some data out of an website. This website has the following structure:

First group item has the following base ID: ***frmGroupList_Label_GroupName*** and then you add ***_2*** or  ***_3*** at the end of this base ID to get the 2nd/3rd group's ID.

Same thing goes for the user item, it has the following base ID: ***frmGroupContacts_TextLabel3*** and then you add ***_2*** or  ***_3*** at the end of this base ID to get the 2nd/3rd users's ID.

What I am trying to do is to get all the users out of each group. And this is how I did it: find the first group, select it and grab all of it users, then, go back to the 2nd group, grab its users, and so on.

```
def grab_contact(number_of_members):
    groupContact = 'frmGroupContacts_TextLabel3'
    contact = browser.find_element_by_id(groupContact).text
    print(contact)
    i = 2
    time.sleep(1)
    # write_to_excel(contact, group)
    while i <= number_of_members:
        group_contact_string = groupContact + '_' + str(i)
        print(group_contact_string)
        try:
            contact = browser.find_element_by_id(group_contact_string).text
            print(contact)
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            # write_to_excel(contact, group)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    time.sleep(3)
```

Same code applies for scraping the groups. And it works, up to a point!! Although the IDs of the groups are different, the IDs of the users are the same from one group to another. Example:

group_id_1 = user_id_1, user_id_2

group_id_2 = user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3, user_id_4, user_id_5

group_id_3 = user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3

The code runs, it goes to group_id_1, grabs user_id_1 and user_id_2 correctly, but when it gets to group_id_2, the user_id_1 and user_id_2 (which are different in matter of content) are EMPTY, and only user_id_3, user_id_4, user_id_5 are correct. Then, when it gets to group_id_3, all of the users are empty.

This has to do with the users having same IDs. As soon as it gets to a certain user ID in a group, I cannot retrieve all the users before that ID in another group. I tried quitting the browser, and reopening a new browser (it doesn't work, the new browser doesn't open), tried refreshing the page (doesn't work), tried opening a new tab (doesn't work).

I think the content of the IDs get stuck in memory when they are accessed, and are not freed when accessing a new group. Any ideas on how to get past this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At least the HTML you're working with.

Comment: Not really, as it contains user emails which I can not share...

Comment: Substitute them for example data.

Comment: <div id="frmGroupContacts_TextLabel3">
 email1
</div>

Each user has something like this, depending on the user's position, you add _2 or _3 to the base ID. And each group, has the same list of IDs for the users, but their content differ. These divs do not change from group to group.

Comment: What works is removing the while loop, and manually change groupContact = 'frmGroupContacts_TextLabel3' for each group before hitting run in PyCharm. Doing this for 90+ groups would take days to complete...

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you but for this question and any future, proving a reprex will help people give you better answers. In this case, it's difficult to guess what the HTML looks like from your description. You can always redact sensitive information, it's the code that matters, not the content :)

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes... it ain't stupid, if it works.

```
def refresh():
    # accessing the groups page
    url = "https://google.com"
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    url = "https://my_url.com"
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
```

While trying to debug this, and finding a solution, I thought: "what if you go to another website, then come back to yours, between group scraping"... and it works! Until I find other solution, I'll stick with this one.